# How To Configure Ant Plugin For Jenkins

Tags: plugins, ant, jenkins

I have marathon Project where I have buid.xml which has many targets all are runned with the help of ant tool. but in the jenkins I need to select a target which I only need to build and test. I need to know how to achieve this using parameterized and invoke Ant ???

Can any one help to me !!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647202/how-do-i-pass-parameters-from-jenkins-to-ant-scripts) is another question which deals with sending parameters to Ant builds.

Comment: that is no fix my prombelm , i want to choose a Classes before start build. like a checkboxes.